# Best practice on docker golang main process communicate with python subprocess

Tags: docker, go, flask, docker-compose, interprocess

I know that a best practice of using docker is to have only one main process in each container and only one `CMD` line running.

My case is I have a `Golang` micro service and the functionality are implemented in python subprocess. Currently the main process just take API calls then invoke the `python` subprocess in `exec` and read the `STDOUT` and `STDERR`.

I want to optimize the architecture like to run python as a service (Flask) only on localhost inside docker. Then my main `Golang` process can use restful `http` call to communicate with the python process.

But that will let 2 service running in a same docker and it's not a main process and a subprocess. Will that be practically bad, Any idea?

Appreciate on all helps.

Comment: When you say optimize, what do you mean? optimize for memory, performance?.. What do you want to optimize exactly, what don't you like about the current solution? Is there a need for two languages?

Comment: Hi @jabbson, when I mention about "optimize", it's mostly about performance. The business logic can only be implemented in python due to library dependencies and the main golang micro service is a must to use in the company.

Comment: Well, if there is a business justified necessity for having two languages, then there is not much you can do, right? Still sounds a bit odd though, to be honest. What does python subprocess calls that you cannot call from Go? Does it have to be in the same container? Could it be a separate container running the python flask app? Then your Go app would be like an API Gateway and Python container would implement a concrete backend logic? Is this something you are after?

Comment: Well actually the company only supports us using Golang as backend language and the associated in-house framework. But the opensource solutions are all python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you have multi service, the best practice is not to deploy them in one container, you are suggested to deploy them in multi containers.

You may use [docker-compose](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/compose/overview/) to help you:

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a YAML file to configure your application’s services. Then, with a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration.

For your scenario, give you a minimal example as next.

**Folder structure:**

```
.
├── docker-compose.yaml
├── flask
│   ├── app.py
│   └── Dockerfile
└── go
    ├── app.go
    └── Dockerfile
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  flask_service:
    build: flask

  go_service:
    build: go
    ports:
    - "9500:9500"
    depends_on:
    - flask_service
```

**go/app.go:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        url := "http://flask_service:9600"
        ret, err := http.Get(url)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        defer ret.Body.Close()

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(ret.Body)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, string(body))
}

func main() {
        http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
        http.ListenAndServe(":9500", nil)
}
```

**go/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM golang:latest as build

WORKDIR /go/app
COPY ./app.go .
RUN go mod init app; go mod tidy; go build

CMD ["/go/app/app"]
```

**flask/app.py:**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hey, we have Flask in a Docker container!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=9600)
```

**flask/Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:alpine3.7

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install flask

COPY . /app

ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

**Execution:**

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "20211203_default" with the default driver
Creating 20211203_flask_service_1 ... done
Creating 20211203_go_service_1    ... done
Attaching to 20211203_flask_service_1, 20211203_go_service_1
```

**Verify:**

```
$ curl http://10.192.244.21:9500
Hey, we have Flask in a Docker container!
```

You could see we visit `9500` port which will route the request to `golang container`, and the `golang container` will then call `flask service container` with api, and finally get the content `Hey, we have Flask in a Docker container!` which produced by `flask`.

Comment: Thank you so much on the detail explanation! Maybe this is the best practice I should apply for deploying both services in same virtual machine.